# Best choice for inserting large volume of data

Tags: c#, mysql, postgresql, sqlite, mariadb

I'm working on a project in **.Net** and using **sqlite** as a database, the goal of this project is to Export huge amount of data to my database so i'm only writing (Inserting) **no reading or updating** .

So i'm trying to improve the performance of inserting (Exporting my data) ,
Switching sqlite is one of my ideas but can't find the final proof to choose another one.

some of db that i'm thinking of (Paradox), but i can't make the choice ,still need some guidance.

Thanks in advance and i appreciate some help.

Edit : Maybe using **Mysql,Postgresql or MariaDb** will be one of the choices, any help or comparison in real life will help alot,Thanks.

Comment: In general for large volumes it is better to turn off indexing for the relevant tables, add the data, and then re-index those table from scratch.  That avoids continually updating the indexes as well as the data.

Comment: There isn't a single index in my tables and i guess that i'm using the best performance in sqlite that's why i'm in a choice to change the whole sqlite thing if there's any better choice

Comment: No indexes?  On a huge table?  How do you intend to use the data?

Comment: my project first export huge data and after finishing the writing process we don't update or insert anymore so indexes are build after writing.By the way any serverless db engines suggestion will be pleased thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use SqlBulkCopy with SqlServer. It can copy a number of rows instead of one by one.

Edit: Here's a link to demonstrate using SqlBulkCopy with a transaction and rollback

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/SqlBulkCopy-example-with-Transaction-Commit-and-Rollback-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: is it the same as using a Transaction ? Like Inserting all records and commit after all

Comment: The SqlBulkCopy command works only when exporting bulk data to a table in SQLServer. And yes it can be used as a transaction. I'll edit the original answer with an example link

Comment: Thanks that didn't help much because i'm already using Transaction and i just used sqlBulkCopy inside my transaction and didn't made any difference,Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you can use a non relational database, you can use MongoDB. MongoDB is a write optimised database that uses a JSON like format to display data. There are drivers for using MongoDB with C#

Comment: Thanks it was one of my choices but can't determine if it will enhance my performance ,and implementing it for test will take more than 2 month

Comment: Here's a comparison between different databases

https://www.arangodb.com/2015/10/benchmark-postgresql-mongodb-arangodb/